# Evaluate sympy.core.add.Add at a point

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I used `derive_by_array` to turn my sympy function into something of type `array of sympy.core.add.Add`. Now I would like to evaluate the expression of type `sympy.core.add.Add` in some given point, how do I do that?

```
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
c = Symbol('c')
f = (-b + sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2 * a)

g = derive_by_array(f, (a, b, c))
type(g[0])   #output: 'sympy.core.add.Add'
```

Me attempting to evaluate the `sympy.core.add.Add` in a point:

`g[0](1,1,0)`

> TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable

So in short, the question is: How do I evaluate `sympy.core.add.Add` in a given point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can substitute a number for each or all of the variables:

```
In [21]: g[0]
Out[21]: 
                               _____________
                              ╱           2 
          c            -b + ╲╱  -4⋅a⋅c + b  
- ────────────────── - ─────────────────────
       _____________               2        
      ╱           2             2⋅a         
  a⋅╲╱  -4⋅a⋅c + b                          

In [22]: g[0].subs({a:1})
Out[22]: 
                       __________
                      ╱  2       
b         c         ╲╱  b  - 4⋅c 
─ - ───────────── - ─────────────
2      __________         2      
      ╱  2                       
    ╲╱  b  - 4⋅c                 

In [23]: g[0].subs({a:1, b:1})
Out[23]: 
                  _________    
       c        ╲╱ 1 - 4⋅c    1
- ─────────── - ─────────── + ─
    _________        2        2
  ╲╱ 1 - 4⋅c                   

In [24]: g[0].subs({a:1, b:1, c:0})
Out[24]: 0
```

Comment: I used `subs` not `sub`.